# Google Docs/Drive and Contacts OAuth 2.0 API access token not working

Tags: google-drive-api, google-oauth, google-contacts-api

I have been trying to access the Google Drive and Contacts OAuth 2.0 API, but to no effect. I had acquired the access token for the same as stated [here](https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2WebServer).

I had specified `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive` and `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/contacts.readonly` as the scope for the Docs/Drive and Contacts APIs respectively (in encodedURI format). The URL I fired to get the authorization code was:

```
https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?scope=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.googleapis.com%2Fauth%2Fcontacts.readonly%20https%3A%2F%2Fwww.googleapis.com%2Fauth%2Fdrive&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.example.com%2Foauth2callback&response_type=code&client_id=xxx&approval_prompt=force
```

And then I fired a POST request to get the access token.

I pass the access token under the `'Authorization'` header to the GET request as:

```
Authorization: Bearer {access_token}
```

When I use this access token in making an API request, I get a 500 Internal server error message, and the JSON response as:

```
{ "error": {  "code": 500,  "message": null }}.
```

Please guide me through this.

Comment: Specify whar flow you are doing, server side or client side?

Answer (score 0):

As you know Oauth2 is in 3 parts.

**Part 1:  Request access**

```
https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?client_id={clientid}.apps.googleusercontent.com&redirect_uri=urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob&scope=https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive,https://www.googleapis.com/auth/contacts.readonly&response_type=code
```

This will display a browser window to your user asking for access.  They will then get an Authentication code.

**Part 2: Exchange Authentication code for Refresh token and access token**

this is a Http **Post**

```
https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token

code=4/X9lG6uWd8-MMJPElWggHZRzyFKtp.QubAT_P-GEwePvB8fYmgkJzntDnaiAI&client_id={ClientId}.apps.googleusercontent.com&client_secret={ClientSecret}&redirect_uri=urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob&grant_type=authorization_code
```

What you will get back will be something like this:

```
{
"access_token" : "ya29.1.AADtN_VSBMC2Ga2lhxsTKjVQ_ROco8VbD6h01aj4PcKHLm6qvHbNtn-_BIzXMw",
"token_type" : "Bearer",
"expires_in" : 3600,
"refresh_token" : "1/J-3zPA8XR1o_cXebV9sDKn_f5MTqaFhKFxH-3PUPiJ4"
}
```

**Part 3 refresh the access token:**
The access token is only good for an hour so after the hour is up you will need to use the refresh token to get a new access token

```
https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token
client_id={ClientId}.apps.googleusercontent.com&client_secret={ClientSecret}&refresh_token=1/ffYmfI0sjR54Ft9oupubLzrJhD1hZS5tWQcyAvNECCA&grant_type=refresh_token
```

You get something like this back

```
{
"access_token" : "ya29.1.AADtN_XK16As2ZHlScqOxGtntIlevNcasMSPwGiE3pe5ANZfrmJTcsI3ZtAjv4sDrPDRnQ",
"token_type" : "Bearer",
"expires_in" : 3600
}
```

Full explanation of how all of this works can be found on the [Google 3 legged oauth2 flow](http://www.daimto.com/google-3-legged-oauth2-flow/) tutorial.  All of this was just ripped from that.  If possible you really should look into using a client library for this they make things much easer.

**Update Chrome is JavaScript:**

The JavaScript does not support type=offline, which would expose the refresh token.

Work around :

1. Generate and store the refresh token Using a server sided language like PHP.
2. Request access tokens every time needs them. Set [immediate=true](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/javascript/reference/referencedocs) so there is no visible interaction with the user (Read this should work I have never tried it)

Comment: Hey, I do not get the refresh token in the response. Could you tell why is it so?

Comment: What language are you using to send your http posts?

Comment: I am using a Chrome extension- Advanced Rest Client to fire the post requests.

Comment: Added an update.  Chrome is javascript you cant see the refreshtoken.

Comment: If he's using a Chrome Extension, it's not quite correct to call it Javascript, in that the usual browser issues don't apply. The Google OAuth servers simply see the POST request, they neither know nor care what language was used to create them. The issue is more likely to be that a refresh token is normally only returned on the initial call, unless he specifies force=true.

Comment: @PriteshLahoti You'll need to paste the actual http calls and responses for us to see what's happening. Feel free to obfuscate the tokens by swapping/deleting some chars at the end, but leave them essentially visible as that helps us check you are using the correct code/token for each call. You should also try using the OAuth Playground and compare it's http traffic with your own.

Comment: @pinoyyid Wow I thought there was no way around that even in chrome apps.  Now I need to test this.

Comment: Don't be confused between chrome apps and chrome extensions. A chrome app is much the same as a web site, and the restrictions you're thinking of apply. A chrome extension can be granted permission to do pretty much anything. In this case, the OP is using a third party Chrome extension to do what most developers do with curl, ie. compose and send arbitrary HTTP requests.

Comment: Ive made oauth work from my chrome extension. It was hard to make it work because of many extension restrictions. Instead use chrome identity which automates it all but user would need to be logged in chrome

Comment: When i wasnt using chrome identity, i did get a refresh token, make sure to pass the offline flag. Open oauth with redirect in a new window. After the redirect, since you are not a server you wont get it the normal way, instead the extension gets the window url and grabs the refresh token from there.

Comment: Yeah, I got it now! I missed the offline flag, and am getting the refresh token using the same chrome extension.

Comment: @DaImTo - I am using the Java client library for my project. Is there any way that I could do the OAuth2 handshake without redirecting the user to a browser for the authorization code exchange?

Comment: The user has to authenticate you though Googles authentication servers. that is a web page.  There is no way around that.     I have done it in a browser control in C# but that is still just a browser.  It has to be displayed to them.